# Replace values in arrays based on condition in python

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I want to replace values in an array based on condition. This is how my array looks like

```
array([[[  0,   0,   0],
        [  0,   0,   0],
        [  0,   0,   0],
        [ 255, 255, 255],
        [  0,   0,   0],
        [  0,   0,   0],
        [255,  255, 255],
        [255,  255, 255]]])
```

I want to replace all values iteratively between [255, 255, 255] and [255, 255, 255] with [255, 255, 255]
        My output should look like:

```
array([[[  0,   0,   0],
        [  0,   0,   0],
        [  0,   0,   0],
        [ 255, 255, 255],
        [ 255, 255, 255],
        [ 255, 255, 255],
        [255,  255, 255],
        [255,  255, 255]]])
```

I have tried this code

```
img_rgb[img_rgb >= 255 & img_rgb <= 255] = 255
```

Comment: Could you provide more code? Are you using some 3rd party library?

Comment: For this particular operation, I have tried above code. No, am not using any third party library.

Comment: What is `array` then?  You have a list nested inside of another list which in turn nested inside of another one. Is it correct?

Comment: Type of above array is 'numpy.ndarray'  when I type "type(img_rgb)"

Comment: `numpy` _is_ a third party library.

Comment: Please suggest any code to accomplish the above task. Thanks

Comment: What if the last row is not [255,255,255]?

Comment: @Divakar What ever the last row we just need to replace values only between [255, 255, 255] and [255, 255, 255]

Answer (score 0):

I'm providing you a way to solve your problem using numpy:

```
import numpy as np

#create a matrix similar to yours:
img = np.zeros((100,100))
replace_line = np.transpose(np.random.randint(100,size=100))
#replace random lines to have a shape like yours
img[40,:] = replace_line
img[87,:] = replace_line

"""
now img should be like that:
 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 .
 .
 x y z ..
 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 x y z ..
 .
 .
"""

#now the actual replacement
#with the condition I take the indexes to start the replacement
#I assume that the rows are always equal so I can take the first column
#as representative of the entire row

non_zero_indexes = img[:,0] >0
non_zero_indexes = np.nonzero(non_zero_indexes)[0]

img[non_zero_indexes[0]:non_zero_indexes[1],:] = replace_line
```

Et voilà